# How to create java counter which resets once 3 digit number is reached or just takes right most 3 numbers

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making a web based code generator which gives doctor's approval to prescribe certain antibiotics, it works by adding the number of the day of the week (i.e. 0 for Sunday, 1 for Monday) with the getDay() function) and a counter which increases with each day (i.e. 232 today, then 233 tomorrow etc...)(using the Math.floor(now/8.64e7) to make a numerical code (like 2232 which looks meaningless to a person, but which a validator can tell is a code generated on Tuesday day 232 (2232 would be OK, but 2231 or 2233 would not be accepted).
Here is the script:

---

```
<script>
    var getcode = function () {
        var now = new Date();
        var fullDaysSinceEpoch = Math.floor(now / 8.64e7) - 16550;
        return '' + now.getDay() + fullDaysSinceEpoch;
    }
</script>
```

---

I want to do it this way rather than make a link between the two programs (because the approval for that would be a nightmare).

My problem is that once the second counter reaches 999 it will continue to become 1000 then 1001 etc... which will go above the max characters allowed in the validator.
 I can keep updating the program and subtracting from the counter, but It is a bit dodgy.

Is there an easier way to construct this counter so it increments every day but only takes the right most 3 numbers from "Math.floor(now / 8.64e7) - 16550" after is reaches 1000? Something like the RIGHT function in excel?

I have thought about using %10, but I will just run into the same problem when the counter reaches 1000 again.

Comment: @failedProgrammer: tags changed. John -- be careful with question tagging, since if you tag incorrectly, the best experts for your problem will miss your question.

Comment: The *fullDaysSinceEpoch* is UTC, but your day number is local, so you will get mis-matches between the day number and the number of days due to timezone differences. Why not just use `%1000`?

Comment: Thanks for the Tag change, and thanks for the comment RobG. I don't want to use a remainder because I want the code's length to stay at a fixed number of characters. I might be wrong, but I think %1000 will change length depending on whether it is divisible by 1000 (i.e. maybe one fullDaysSinceEpoch will be 17000 and then %1000 will be 0, but I want 3 numbers which will correspond somehow to which day it is).
 The UTC is definitely a problem which I didn't think about.. I'll update the getDay() with now.getUTCDay();
 Thanks for the comments